# Symfony Form choices customize the get url

Tags: forms, symfony, get, symfony-2.1

So I have a search bar form that I need to temporarly wire up to a legacy non-symfony page.
the current get url looks like the following (url-decoded)

```
http://localhost:9090/lagacy_page?query=test&platforms[]=Mac,Windows
```

but I need to make the url look like the following

```
http://localhost:9090/lagacy_page?query=test&platforms=Mac,Windows
```

Symfony is making platforms an array, does anyone no if there is a way to force it to be a comma delimitated list?

Here is the buildForm method

```
/**
 * method to build search bar form
 *
 * @param \Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface $builder
 * @param array $options
 */
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    // the platform selector
    $builder->add('platform', 'choice',
        ['choices' => [
            Platforms::ALL => 'All Software', // TODO: need to translate this
            Platforms::WINDOWS => 'Windows',
            Platforms::MAC => 'Mac',
            Platforms::IOS => 'iOS',
            Platforms::ANDROID => 'Android',
        ],
        'multiple' => true,
        'expanded' => true]);

    // the actual search bar
    $builder->add('query', 'search');

}
```

Comment: How do you save those platforms in your database? Do you have an ENUM for that, or a platforms table?

Answer (score 0):

You will want to override how Symfony2 renders the choice field.

The documentation has plenty of information about [how to customize Form rendering](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html).

If only the choice type of search form needs this, you will need to [create a custom type](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/create_custom_field_type.html) in order to avoid conflicts with the other forms of your website.

In short, if you override the `choice` type using the first doc and you do not use a custom type every `choice` type will use the same behavior (the one you will create for your search form) and you probably don't want that.

An easy alternative solution would be to apply a custom `form_div_layout.html.twig` file directly to the form object. There wouldn't be any conflicts with other forms as you would use a custom template just for the search form.

After reading the docs my answer will make more sense and you will be able to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use two form elements, since Symfony doing it in right way (according to HTML specifcation)

```
/**
 * method to build search bar form
 *
 * @param \Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface $builder
 * @param array $options
 */
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    // the platform selector
    $builder->add('platform_choice', 'choice',
        ['choices' => [
            Platforms::ALL => 'All Software', // TODO: need to translate this
            Platforms::WINDOWS => 'Windows',
            Platforms::MAC => 'Mac',
            Platforms::IOS => 'iOS',
            Platforms::ANDROID => 'Android',
        ],
        'multiple' => true,
        'expanded' => true,
        'attr' => [
            'class' => 'platform-sorce'
        ])
    ->add('platform', 'hidden', [
        'attr' => [
            'class' => 'real-platform'
        ]
    ]);

    // the actual search bar
    $builder->add('query', 'search');
}
```

Then add  JS updating you hidden field, since 'platform_choice' is disabled and wont be send.

```
$(function(){
     var $real_platform = $('.real-platform'),
         $platform_source = $('.platform-source');

     $platform_source.change(function(){
         $real_platform.val($(this).val().join(',');
     });

     $('#your-form").submit(function(){
         $platform_source.attr('disabled', true);

         return true;
     });
});
```